# C++ converting string to char is not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have the following code to convert a string to char :

```
string tempLine = dataLine[studentIndex];
char str = tempLine.c_str();
```

but this line returns an error : " a value of type "constant char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char".

How can I fix this issue??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be:

```
const char *str = tempLine.c_str();
```

Note that you're not supposed to change the content of the string. Generally, its not a good way to work with C++ strings. If you really have to fully convert a C++ string to C string - allocate memory and use `strcpy` to copy data, don't use the C++ string buffers directly.

**edit** for your request in the comments: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for C++ learning resources.

Comment: I know what const is, but what is the "*" before str for?

Comment: @Ahoura - `*` means **pointer**. `char` is a single character, you're dealing with a string. So you need a pointer to a sequence of characters, not a single character. If you don't know what `*` means, I'm sure you're not supposed to do what you're doing.

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi If your question really is what `*` means, then stop right now and get a good C++ book to start with.

Comment: @Ahoura - It means that it's a pointer instead of just a char. Since strings can contain several characters, the string is rather the memory address of the first character of the string.

Comment: @ChristianRau if you are not going to be helpful I honestly dont see why you would even bother posting. its a question I had in mind and if you dont feel like you want to help out then just go ahead and leave this page and help other people.

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi Maybe it sounded a bit rude, but it wasn't meant that way. Honestly, if you don't know what a pointer is, then you should first learn the basics from some real learning resource as otherwise the answers to this question just won't buy you anything.

Comment: Really, what @Christian Rau said is the most helpful thing that can be said here...

Comment: @ChristianRau orite thanks for the reply, now that you rephrased it doesnt sound bad BUT I am learning C++ but unfortunately the instructor in my uni is fairly useless when it comes to knowing stuff... thats why I had to ask the question here... could you recommend me a book on C++??

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi Try [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/docs/books/eckel/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert a `const char*`, which is what `std::string::c_str()` returns, to `char`. Change:

```
char str = tempLine.c_str();
```

to:

```
const char* str = tempLine.c_str();
```

Note this does not copy the characters in `tempLine` to `str`, `str` just refers to the characters in `tempLine`.